# Keep Firefox as default browser but open youtube links in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, thunderbird

Is there a possibility to open Youtube/Twitch/... - Links in Chrome instead of my default browser (Firefox)?

The reason is, that all browsers are very slow on my (fresh) installation of 15.10 but things like Youtube, Twitch, Google maps are unusable in Firefox. So, if I click on a link that's on Youtube, I'd like it to be opened in Chrome instead of Firefox. Especially, when I click on links in my RSS in Thunderbird. I tried the "Open with" Extension in Thunderbird, but when I right click on the link on the URL it only gives me "Copy Link location".

Comment: There's an addon called "open with".

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the last sentence, when I right click on the link on the URL it only gives me "Copy Link location".

Comment: You could set your default browser to a shell script that determines based on the URL what browser to open.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to go ahead and copy the link location. Then paste the URL into the address bar in Chrome. To save time,have Chrome running the background before you open Thunderbird.

Probably better, though, is to install the add-on called "**Open-With**" by Geoff Lankow. This allows you to select on the fly the browser you want to open a particular link. You can find it for Thunderbird [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/open-with/). There is also Firefox version [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/).

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the last sentence, when I right click on the link on the URL (using the Open with extension) it only gives me "Copy Link location"